# A charecter array of arbitary length with 'R', 'B', 'W' is need to be sorted in that order

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

There is char array of n length. Array can have elements only from of any order R, B, W.
     You need to sort array so that order should R,B,W i.e. all R will come first followed by B and then W.
     **Constraints:**   Time complexity is O(n) and space complexity should be O(1).
     **Assumption:** You can assume one swap method is given with signature swap(char[] arr, int index1, int index2)
                 that swaps number in unit time.
     **method given to implement:** public sort(char[]array);

Here is my implementation of it. Better solution from anyone is appreciated. Anyone is free to pointme out mistakes if I any.

```
 public static void sort(char[] arr){
     int rIndex = 0, wIndex = arr.length -1;
     for (int i = 0 ; i <= wIndex; i ++ ){
         if ( arr[i] == 'R' ){
             swap(arr, i , rIndex ++ );
         } else if (arr[i] == 'W' ){
             swap(arr, i , wIndex -- );
         }else if ( arr[i] == 'B' ){
             swap(arr, i , rIndex );
         }
     }
    }
```

Comment: If there's no problem with your code, then this is off-topic for StackOverflow.  If you need more eyes, you might try asking at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Well, but there are problems. For example, `swap()` only takes two arguments according to the assignment. (But I don't get the `rIndex++`, `wIndex--` and `rIndex` parameters anyway...). Actually, I don't understand anything about how this program is supposed to work.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Swap method needs three param to swap. Thats a mistake. I edited just.

Comment: Isn't this the [Dutch national flag problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem)? I don't think you need to `swap` in all three `if` conditions.

Comment: @Blastfurnace an example below is appreciated??

Comment: There is `C++` and `Java` code on that Wikipedia page.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about requesting help reviewing working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using swap:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] arr = "WBRBBWBRRBWBR".toCharArray();
    sort(arr);
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(arr));
}
public static void sort(char[] arr) {
    int rCount = sortFirst(arr, 0, 'R');
    sortFirst(arr, rCount, 'B');
}
public static int sortFirst(char[] arr, int offset, char ch) {
    int chCount = 0;
    for (int i = offset; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == ch) {
            if (i > offset + chCount)
                swap(arr, offset + chCount, i);
            chCount++;
        }
    }
    return chCount;
}
public static void swap(char[] arr, int index1, int index2) {
    char h = arr[index1];
    arr[index1] = arr[index2];
    arr[index2] = h;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this question is in the scope of SO, but I'll present an alternative solution nonetheless mainly because I found the task specification annoying. No actual "sorting" is required. :)

```
public static void sort(char[] arr) {
    int r = 0, b = 0, w = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == 'R') r++;
        else if(arr[i] == 'B') b++;
        else w++;
    }
    int o = 0;
    for(; r > 0; r--) arr[o++] = 'R';
    for(; b > 0; b--) arr[o++] = 'B';
    for(; w > 0; w--) arr[o++] = 'W';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like your solution, but the question asked was expecting usages of swap method.
Moreover on a performance perspective your solution has a bit high space and time complexity than above.

Comment: +1, this is similar to a radix sort.  You could still make it a sort (a non-comparative sort) by doing a second pass on the array and copying the element into the correct array position (such that this would then work if the `R/B/W` was a property of each element, rather than the element itself).  This wouldn't violate the `O(n)` constraint.

Comment: @MohdAdnan: This solution is both `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space, not sure why you think it violates those.

Comment: "high time complexity" -- This is not true. It's still the exact same `O(n)` complexity. If you're arguing that it takes longer *constant* time (which is another thing), that's not necessarily true either, since it may be more cache-friendly and branch-friendly than other solutions.

Comment: Yes I actually meant constant time complexity. I don't follow how it is more cache friendly and branch friendly? Do you mean another solution has method calls and it doesn't have?

Comment: As for cache-friendliness, it has better memory locality behavior, so the processor is more likely to be able to stream and preload memory and avoid latency from random accesses. As for branch-friendliness, as long as the compiler is smart enough to implement the `if` statements in the first loop with `cmov` instructions, the only actual branches that the program even contains are the loops themselves, which can fit into the trace-caches of modern CPUs and avoid branch mispredictions and therefore pipeline bubbles altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, here is improved version of my above algorithm. It has one less swap call and uses switches rather than if else block

```
public static void sort(char[] arr){
     int rIndex = 0, wIndex = arr.length -1;
     for (int i = 0 ; i <= wIndex;){
        switch(arr[i]){
          case 'R':
            swap(arr, i, rIndex ++ );
            i ++;
            break;
          case 'W':
            swap(arr, i, wIndex -- );
            break;
          case 'B':
            i ++;
            break;
          default: 
             throw new IllegalArguementException(arr[i] + " is not allowed in the array");

       }
   }
}
```

Comment: don't do this kinda code in the future... it's a mess.. don't use switch like this and don't use default like this. try to do one thing at a time, make the code visible and then implement everything and don't throw illegal argument exceptions in default case :)

Comment: could you also elaborate why with all don'ts :) ? why you find this a mess? what you suggest then? For me -
switch is faster and readable than if else nesting. 
throwing exception from default is recommended from most of the cases when u write fail fast code, that makes your code to be written specifically for given scenario, scenarios those are not handled by your method should be thrown back like I did.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest sort possible is `QuickSort` and it's time efficiency is `O(n log n)` as average and worst case `O(n*n)`. Best case `O(n)` if it's already sorted...

Getting the efficiency you want it is not possible.
What you have to do first is to make a method that compares 2 chars and do your algorithm there. then make one method that swaps characters.

**If you want to achieve that efficiency you don't have to sort them. you have to count them and build a character array in the order you desired as @Dolda2000 did. You can't sort faster than `QuickSort`**

Comment: is it Fox if I am not mistaken?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to ask me :)

Comment: *"The fastest sort possible is QuickSort"* -- This not always true. In some cases (including this), radix sort can be applied, which is O(n).

Comment: I know one from Romania with name Alex, your face is pretty similar to him. He is also known as Fox hence asked are u same Fox (Alex) ?
:)
And I agree with Dolda2000, Quick sort is not fastest always. It depends upon usages to usage.